# multiple labels in legend function

Tags: r, legend

I want to add legend in my plot as in picture attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhjKe.jpg

- black line for logistic growth model
- red line for exponential decay model
- just dot for third heading using pch
- just plus for fourth heading using pch

but when i use `pch` it gives for all four headings. I want simple black and red lines for first and second. and simple dot and plus for third and fourth. please guide me what would be the code? I am using as follows:

```
legend(100, 2500, legend = c("logistic growth model", "exponential decay model", "observation in years 100-150", "observation in years 151-200"))
```

after this i dont how to add next functions. please help

Answer (score 0):

Add the following 3 arguments into your function `legend()`:

- **Plotting symbols :** `pch = c(NA, NA, 1, 3)`
- **Line types :** `lty = c(1, 1, NA, NA)`
- **Colors :** `col = c(1, 2, 1, 4))`

The main point is that using **NA** to undo the influences of `pch` and `lty`.

[image]